# Branch.io deep link onLinkCreate never called

Tags: android, branch.io

Can't seem to get Branch.io to call onLinkCreate method.

Copy/Pasted the documentation to a method called out by a button press.
Here is the method:

```
public void shareBuilding(View v){
    Log.i("DEEP_LINK", "Composing deep link...");
    BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
            .setCanonicalIdentifier("item/12345")
            .setTitle("My Content Title")
            .setContentDescription("My Content Description")
            .setContentImageUrl("https://example.com/mycontent-12345.png")
            .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)
            .addContentMetadata("property1", "blue")
            .addContentMetadata("property2", "red");

    Log.i("DEEP_LINK", "BranchUniversalObject created");
    LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
            .setChannel("unk")
            .setFeature("sharing")
            .addControlParameter("$desktop_url", "http://www.example.com")
            .addControlParameter("$ios_url", "http://www.example.com");

    Log.i("DEEP_LINK", "LinkProperties created");
    branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(this, linkProperties, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                Log.i("DEEP_LINK", "Deep link composed: " + url);
            }else{
                Log.i("DEEP_LINK", "Error composing deep link: " + error.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

This is all from the documentation but onLinkCreate method is never called.

Here is the android monitor output:

```
DEEP_LINK: Composing deep link...
DEEP_LINK: BranchUniversalObject created
DEEP_LINK: LinkProperties created
```

onLinkCreate is never called. No error messages are thrown. 
I seem to be running into a wall with Branch.io methods (from generating this link to opening intent with deep links) so I'm afraid that there might be something I am missing or doing compleatly wrong.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml content:

```
 <!-- This is for Branch,io deep linking -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Landing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <!-- This is for brach.io deep linking-->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="foo" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: to rule out the obvious, have you replaced the `key_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` placeholder in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file with your actual Branch key? If the key isn't valid, the SDK won't be able to initialize a session, which could definitely be causing the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Another thing to check: make sure you have [auto session management enabled](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/#enable-auto-session-management)